# При скроле страницы, как узнать что скрол уперся вниз?

Tags: javascript

подскажите пожалста, хочу сделать открытие поп-апа при окончании скрола основной страницы с помощью **js**.
Чтобы *окно* появлялось если скрол уперся *вниз* и закрывалось когда положение скрола менялось.

пробовал вот так

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
 let page = document.querySelector('.page');
 if (page.scrollHeight - page.scrollTop === page.clientHeight) {
 console.log('скрол кончился')
 } else {
 console.log('ещё нет')
 }
 });
```

Comment: 1. Пытались искать? Если нет, поищите, если да, то в чём у вас возникли проблемы? 2. Какие у вас попытки? Опубликовывать не слова, а код. Вопрос можно отредактировать кнопкой [`Править`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1455250/edit), в комментариях код не публиковать.

Comment: на самом деле очень хороший вопрос и совсем не простой, как кажется. нужно window.pageYOffset сравнить с [высотой документа](https://learn.javascript.ru/size-and-scroll-window#shirina-vysota-dokumenta)

Comment: NNL993 я пробовал разные варианты решения, сейчас код опишу через кнопку править. Алексей, через ваш вариант если я верно понял, должно получиться чтото вроде такого ? window.addEventListener ('scroll', function() { document.querySelector('.page').innerHTML = pageYOffset; 
и дальше page.scrollHeight === pageYOffset});  ??